# CoreData fetched object becomes nil when tried to update in completion handler - Swift4

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, swift4, nsmanagedobject

```
        let bgContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)

        let moc = appDelegate.coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
        bgContext.parent = moc
        bgContext.perform({

            let fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<ReservationsEntity>
            let request: NSFetchRequest<ReservationsEntity> = ReservationsEntity.fetchRequest()
            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(ReservationsEntity.reservedDate), ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isSynced == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
            fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

            do{
                try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
                for reservationEntity in fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!{

                    print(reservationEntity.isSynced!)
                    let params = BaseViewController.getReservationDictionaryForOffline(reservation: reservationEntity)
                    ServerCalls.addReservationToServer(parametersForReservation: params, kindOfScreen: 0, completionHandler: { (response) in
                        print(reservationEntity.isSynced!)

                        reservationEntity.isSynced = true

                    })
                }

            } catch{

            }


        })
```

**Issue**: Hello!I have a use case saying `AddReservation` where I add a record to CoreData Entity named `ReservationsEntity` with an attribute `isSynced` to `false` initially. I also make a server call simultaneously and once the server call returns, I am trying to update the flag `isSynced` to `true`. But after the server call returns my CoreData object is becoming nil.

As per the code posted above, first `print(reservationEntity.isSynced!)`shows `false` in the debugger. When I try to print/ access `reservationEntity` after `ServerCalls.addReservationToServer` returns, app crashes as the `reservationEntity` object becomes `nil`.

I have been trying to fix it for the past few days trying different ways but of no use. What's the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Why are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController` instead of a simple `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: I don't think you can use the `reservationEntity` inside the closure since it only exists while the for loop is executing. Better to store each response into an array inside the closure and then match them against the `fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects` array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
let bgContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
bgContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.coreData.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

And remove

```
let moc = appDelegate.coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
bgContext.parent = moc
```